# Oninput function not firing after window.onload

Tags: javascript, input, javascript-objects, dom-events, nodelist

I have a object named `MYMODCLASS` that contains all my module `functions`.  One of these functions `addNumberValues(id, getId)` loops through a collection of number inputs using the `getElementsByName` method and adds the values to check that the values are less than 100.

When I invoke the function using the following notation:

```
window.onload = document.getElementsByName('grade').oninput = MYMODCLASS.addNumberValues('info', 'grade');
```

The function only fires once when the document loaded, but not again.

When I invoke it as a parameter to an input element is works consistently:

```
<input type="number" value=0 id="ind" name="grade" min="0" max="100" oninput="MYMODCLASS.addNumberValues('info', 'grade')" required>
<input type="number" value=0 id="nv" name="grade" min="0" max="100" oninput="MYMODCLASS.addNumberValues('info', 'grade')" required>
```

The problem with the latter invocation is that I have to repeat the `oninput` parameter 30 times.  Therefore, I want to use the former invocation for the ``addNumberValues function.

```
MYMODCLASS.addNumberValues = function (id, getId) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    var el = document.getElementsByName(getId);
    var i = 0;
    el.forEach((ite) => {
        console.log(ite.value);
        if (!isNaN(parseFloat(ite.value)) && isFinite(ite.value)) {
            if (i === 0) {
                i = parseFloat(ite.value);
            } else {
                i = parseFloat(i) + parseFloat(ite.value);
            }
        }
    })
    console.log(i);
    if (i > 100 || i < 0) {
        element.className = 'lbwarn';
        element.innerText = i;
        alert("Grade exceeds 100!")
    } else {
        element.className = 'lbinfo';
        element.innerText = i;
    }
};
```

**Edit**
So after reading the comments I decided to create a loop that sets the function for each individual element by id.  But this is still not working.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var numel = document.getElementsByName('grade');
    numel.forEach((p) => {
         console.log(p.id);
         document.getElementById(p.id).oninput = MYMODCLASS.addNumberValues('info', 'grade');
    })
}
```

How can I get the invocation to work consistently using my last method?

Comment: `document.getElementsByName('grade').oninput` - `getElementsByName` returns a HTML collection, and you can't bind events to collections, only individual elements.

Comment: @Utkanos I did not know that.  Thank you.  Would the alternative be to add an eventListener on the `onkeyup` event?  Or, what is the alternative to bind the function on a group of number inputs?

Comment: @Hmerman6006 you can loop over the collection and bind the event one by one

Comment: @LuudJacobs Thanks for the suggestion.  See edit of 20 min ago.  I already tried that, but for some reason it isn't working.  Any ideas why?

Comment: In your loop variable `p` is already a DOM element, so no need to use the id and get it again. You should wrap the call to `MYMODCLASS.addNumberValues` in a function: `p.oninput = () => { MYMODCLASS.addNumberValues('a', 'b'); }`. In your current code it will call the function directly for every `numel`

Comment: @LuudJacobs Wow! That is some high level stuff.  Does the two empty parenthesis represent a function?  That solved it.  If you make your comments the answer I will mark it as such.  One up for both Utkanos and LuudJacobs.

Comment: Arrow functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions